# Installed Gnu Coreutils, but no grep present

Tags: homebrew

I have installed some time ago the Gnu Coreutils using Homebrew, and choose the installation variant that the tools should be installed with a new name, with `g` as prefix, since I want to use them along the BSD variants.

This works fine. I have for instance /usr/local/cat (the BSD), and I have a /usrl/lcal/bin/gcat, which is a symlink to `../Cellar/coreutils/8.29/bin/gcat`.

However I don't have a `ggrep`. Showing `/usr/local/bin/*grep` gives me

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 30 May 15 10:56 /usr/local/bin/lzegrep -> ../Cellar/xz/5.4.3/bin/lzegrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 30 May 15 10:56 /usr/local/bin/lzfgrep -> ../Cellar/xz/5.4.3/bin/lzfgrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 29 May 15 10:56 /usr/local/bin/lzgrep -> ../Cellar/xz/5.4.3/bin/lzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 36 Apr 21 11:49 /usr/local/bin/msggrep -> ../Cellar/gettext/0.21.1 /bin/msggrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 35 Apr 21 11:49 /usr/local/bin/pcre2grep -> ../Cellar/pcre2/10.42/bin/pcre2grep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 30 May 15 10:56 /usr/local/bin/xzegrep -> ../Cellar/xz/5.4.3/bin/xzegrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 30 May 15 10:56 /usr/local/bin/xzfgrep -> ../Cellar/xz/5.4.3/bin/xzfgrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 29 May 15 10:56 /usr/local/bin/xzgrep -> ../Cellar/xz/5.4.3/bin/xzgrep
lrwxr-xr-x 1 33 Apr 21 11:49 /usr/local/bin/zstdgrep -> ../Cellar/zstd/1.5.5/bin/zstdgrep
```

A `/usr/local/Cellar/grep` does not exist. How can I get at the Gnu grep easily? Is there a reason why the Coreutils exclude `grep`?

Comment: You could install GNU grep with grep brew formulae (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grep)